# With NextJS, I want to programmatically access assetPrefix from next.config.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I include in my `_document.js` several static files and fonts that I want to put prefix with `assetPrefix` if there is one specified in `next.config.js`. My current `next.config.js` is as following:

```
module.exports = (phase) => {
        return withTypescript(
            withCSS(
                withImages(
                    withOffline({
                        env,
                        useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
                        assetPrefix: isProd ? 'https://d28d4ipdckjadl.cloudfront.net' : '',
                        inlineImageLimit: 16384,
                        ...
```

That is, my `_document.js` has code like the following:

```
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href={'/static/bootstrap.css'}
 />
```

I think it might be webpack thing so I'm tagging that also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on client-side / server-side needs, try creating a `publicRuntimeConfig` and / or `serverRuntimeConfig` object with the `assetPrefix`'s value.

```js
module.exports = (phase) => {
        return withTypescript(
            withCSS(
                withImages(
                    withOffline({
                        env,
                        useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
                        assetPrefix: isProd ? 'https://d28d4ipdckjadl.cloudfront.net' : '',
                        publicRuntimeConfig: {
                            MY_ASSET_PREFIX: isProd ? 'https://d28d4ipdckjadl.cloudfront.net' : ''
                        },
                        serverRuntimeConfig: {
                            MY_ASSET_PREFIX: isProd ? 'https://d28d4ipdckjadl.cloudfront.net' : ''
                        }
}
```

Then you can access the variable in your `_document.js` like this:

```js
import getConfig from 'next/config';

...

const MY_ASSET_PREFIX = getConfig().publicRuntimeConfig.MY_ASSET_PREFIX;
```

Comment: At least that has them both in the same file.  I could do that but was hoping I could just access the one value.  Having two truths is not optimal and need to remember that.